# debugng 2GB AWS server hang with Netbox, Python 3.8

Tags: server, aws, sysrq

I have a AWS t3.micro 2GB 20.04 machine, that i want to use for Netbox software. I created a RDS instance in AWS, so no DB problem on computing, back-end side.

When i complete all steps in the Netbox guide with Nginx and Python3, i'm unable to use VM in no way, no SSH, console etc.

I connected AWS VM serial console port with Putty, i can send break command and sysrq keys, no problem until here.

Both while rebooting and sysrq Out Of Memory task kill, i can see python3 in Out of memory. First thing i don't understand how can be a lightweight software like Netbox consume high memory? It's not normal i guess.

Second, even sysrq kills OOM python3, i can't get list of CPU traceback with sysrq. Waited for almost 10 minutes, no way.

Where we can start to troubleshoot?

Thanks

```
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~# ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax | sort -b -k3 -r
[38185.422338] sysrq: HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-task                                                                  s(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-b                                                                  acktrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o                                                                  ) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmo                                                                  unt(u) show-blocked-tasks(w) dump-ftrace-buffer(z)
[38271.650186] sysrq: Show Memory
    330 root      2.3 /sbin/multipathd -d -s
   1452 netbox   15.4 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python3 /opt/netbox/netbox/manage.py                                                                   rqworker high default low
   1336 netbox   10.8 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python3 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/gunicorn                                                                   --pid /var/tmp/netbox.pid --pythonpath /opt/netbox/netbox --config /opt/netbox/                                                                  gunicorn.py netbox.wsgi
   1335 netbox   10.8 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python3 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/gunicorn                                                                   --pid /var/tmp/netbox.pid --pythonpath /opt/netbox/netbox --config /opt/netbox/                                                                  gunicorn.py netbox.wsgi
    862 netbox   10.8 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python3 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/gunicorn                                                                   --pid /var/tmp/netbox.pid --pythonpath /opt/netbox/netbox --config /opt/netbox/                                                                  gunicorn.py netbox.wsgi
    863 netbox   10.7 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python3 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/gunicorn                                                                   --pid /var/tmp/netbox.pid --pythonpath /opt/netbox/netbox --config /opt/netbox/                                                                  gunicorn.py netbox.wsgi
    860 netbox   10.7 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python3 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/gunicorn                                                                   --pid /var/tmp/netbox.pid --pythonpath /opt/netbox/netbox --config /opt/netbox/                                                                  gunicorn.py netbox.wsgi
    639 root      1.9 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
    584 netbox    1.9 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python3 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/gunicorn                                                                   --pid /var/tmp/netbox.pid --pythonpath /opt/netbox/netbox --config /opt/netbox/                                                                  gunicorn.py netbox.wsgi
   1718 root      1.6 apt-get check -qq
    767 root      1.3 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended                                                                  -upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
    585 root      1.3 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startu                                                                  p-triggers
    865 root      0.9 /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6312/ssm-agent-worker
    456 systemd+  0.8 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
    611 root      0.6 /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6312/amazon-ssm-agent
   1779 root      0.6 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python /opt/netbox/netbox/manage.py h                                                                  ousekeeping
      1 root      0.5 /sbin/init
    791 root      0.4 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D -o AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/shar                                                                  e/ec2-instance-connect/eic_run_authorized_keys %u %f -o AuthorizedKeysCommandUse                                                                  r ec2-instance-connect [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
    723 www-data  0.4 nginx: worker process
    722 www-data  0.4 nginx: worker process
    764 root      0.4 /usr/sbin/ModemManager
    203 root      0.4 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
    453 systemd+  0.4 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
    165 root      0.4 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
   1000 root      0.4 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
   1006 root      0.4 -bash
   1001 root      0.4 (sd-pam)
   1861 root      0.3 ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax
    499 root      0.3 /usr/sbin/cron -f
    642 root      0.3 /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd
    737 redis     0.3 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
    500 message+  0.3 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork                                                                   --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
    420 systemd+  0.3 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
    640 root      0.3 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
    610 syslog    0.2 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
    521 root      0.2 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
    671 daemon    0.2 /usr/sbin/atd -f
   1723 root      0.2 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
    604 root      0.2 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
    837 root      0.2 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty1 linux
   1700 root      0.2 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily lock_is_held instal                                                                  l
   1696 root      0.2 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily install
    816 root      0.2 /bin/login -p --
   1862 root      0.1 sort -b -k3 -r
   1725 root      0.1 run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
    711 root      0.1 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master                                                                  _process on;
    491 root      0.1 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
    116 root      0.0 [zswap-shrink]
     30 root      0.0 [writeback]
     87 root      0.0 [watchdogd]
    101 root      0.0 [vfio-irqfd-clea]
     82 root      0.0 [tpm_dev_wq]
     11 root      0.0 [rcu_tasks_trace]
     10 root      0.0 [rcu_tasks_rude_]
     13 root      0.0 [rcu_sched]
      4 root      0.0 [rcu_par_gp]
      3 root      0.0 [rcu_gp]
     29 root      0.0 [oom_reaper]
     97 root      0.0 [nvme-wq]
     98 root      0.0 [nvme-reset-wq]
     99 root      0.0 [nvme-delete-wq]
      5 root      0.0 [netns]
      9 root      0.0 [mm_percpu_wq]
    103 root      0.0 [mld]
     20 root      0.0 [migration/1]
     14 root      0.0 [migration/0]
     84 root      0.0 [md]
    117 root      0.0 [kworker/u5:0]
   1858 root      0.0 [kworker/u4:3-writeback]
   1839 root      0.0 [kworker/u4:1+loop1]
   1852 root      0.0 [kworker/u4:0-writeback]
    693 root      0.0 [kworker/1:4-mm_percpu_wq]
    100 root      0.0 [kworker/1:1H-events_highpri]
   1333 root      0.0 [kworker/1:1-events]
     23 root      0.0 [kworker/1:0H-events_highpri]
    126 root      0.0 [kworker/0:2-events]
     89 root      0.0 [kworker/0:1H-kblockd]
   1417 root      0.0 [kworker/0:1-events]
      7 root      0.0 [kworker/0:0H-events_highpri]
     95 root      0.0 [kthrotld]
      2 root      0.0 [kthreadd]
     92 root      0.0 [kswapd0]
    113 root      0.0 [kstrp]
     21 root      0.0 [ksoftirqd/1]
     12 root      0.0 [ksoftirqd/0]
     32 root      0.0 [ksmd]
    328 root      0.0 [kmpathd]
    327 root      0.0 [kmpath_rdacd]
    329 root      0.0 [kmpath_handlerd]
     79 root      0.0 [kintegrityd]
     28 root      0.0 [khungtaskd]
     33 root      0.0 [khugepaged]
     24 root      0.0 [kdevtmpfs]
     31 root      0.0 [kcompactd0]
     80 root      0.0 [kblockd]
     26 root      0.0 [kauditd]
    326 root      0.0 [kaluad]
    123 root      0.0 [jbd2/nvme0n1p1-]
    104 root      0.0 [ipv6_addrconf]
     25 root      0.0 [inet_frag_wq]
     19 root      0.0 [idle_inject/1]
     15 root      0.0 [idle_inject/0]
    124 root      0.0 [ext4-rsv-conver]
    214 root      0.0 [ena]
     85 root      0.0 [edac-poller]
     93 root      0.0 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
     86 root      0.0 [devfreq_wq]
    283 root      0.0 [cryptd]
     18 root      0.0 [cpuhp/1]
     17 root      0.0 [cpuhp/0]
    122 root      0.0 [charger_manager]
     81 root      0.0 [blkcg_punt_bio]
     83 root      0.0 [ata_sff]
     96 root      0.0 [acpi_thermal_pm]
    492 root      0.0 /usr/sbin/acpid
   1778 root      0.0 /bin/sh /etc/cron.daily/netbox-housekeeping
   1724 root      0.0 /bin/sh -c test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-part                                                                  s --report /etc/cron.daily )
    PID USER     %MEM COMMAND
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~# [38805.151817] sysrq: Show backtrace of all active CPUs

root@ip-172-31-45-233:~# [40221.971222] sysrq: Manual OOM execution
[40221.975154] Out of memory: Killed process 1452 (python3) total-vm:243236kB, anon-rss:117172kB, file-rss:1196kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:115 pgtables:364kB oom_score_adj:0

root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~# ^C
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#


root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#

root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~# [40380.324029] sysrq: Show Memory

root@ip-172-31-45-233:~# ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax | sort -b -k3 -r
   1913 root      3.2 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
   1922 netbox    3.0 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python3 /opt/netbox/netbox/manage.py rqworker high default low
    330 root      2.3 /sbin/multipathd -d -s
    639 root      2.0 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
    584 netbox    2.0 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python3 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/gunicorn --pid /var/tmp/netbox.pid --pythonpath /opt/netbox/netbox --config /opt/netbox/gunicorn.py netbox.wsgi
   1336 netbox   10.9 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python3 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/gunicorn --pid /var/tmp/netbox.pid --pythonpath /opt/netbox/netbox --config /opt/netbox/gunicorn.py netbox.wsgi
    863 netbox   10.9 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python3 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/gunicorn --pid /var/tmp/netbox.pid --pythonpath /opt/netbox/netbox --config /opt/netbox/gunicorn.py netbox.wsgi
    862 netbox   10.9 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python3 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/gunicorn --pid /var/tmp/netbox.pid --pythonpath /opt/netbox/netbox --config /opt/netbox/gunicorn.py netbox.wsgi
   1779 root     10.9 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python /opt/netbox/netbox/manage.py housekeeping
   1335 netbox   10.8 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python3 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/gunicorn --pid /var/tmp/netbox.pid --pythonpath /opt/netbox/netbox --config /opt/netbox/gunicorn.py netbox.wsgi
    860 netbox   10.8 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/python3 /opt/netbox/venv/bin/gunicorn --pid /var/tmp/netbox.pid --pythonpath /opt/netbox/netbox --config /opt/netbox/gunicorn.py netbox.wsgi
    767 root      1.3 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
    585 root      1.3 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
    865 root      0.9 /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6312/ssm-agent-worker
    456 systemd+  0.8 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
    611 root      0.6 /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6312/amazon-ssm-agent
      1 root      0.6 /sbin/init
    453 systemd+  0.5 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
    791 root      0.4 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D -o AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/share/ec2-instance-connect/eic_run_authorized_keys %u %f -o AuthorizedKeysCommandUser ec2-instance-connect [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
    723 www-data  0.4 nginx: worker process
    722 www-data  0.4 nginx: worker process
    764 root      0.4 /usr/sbin/ModemManager
    737 redis     0.4 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
    500 message+  0.4 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
    165 root      0.4 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
   1000 root      0.4 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
   1006 root      0.4 -bash
   1001 root      0.4 (sd-pam)
   1931 root      0.3 ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax
    491 root      0.3 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
    203 root      0.3 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
    420 systemd+  0.3 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
    640 root      0.3 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
    610 syslog    0.2 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
    521 root      0.2 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
    499 root      0.2 /usr/sbin/cron -f
    671 daemon    0.2 /usr/sbin/atd -f
   1723 root      0.2 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
    642 root      0.2 /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd
    837 root      0.2 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty1 linux
   1700 root      0.2 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily lock_is_held install
   1696 root      0.2 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily install
    816 root      0.2 /bin/login -p --
   1932 root      0.1 sort -b -k3 -r
   1725 root      0.1 run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
    711 root      0.1 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
    604 root      0.1 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
    116 root      0.0 [zswap-shrink]
     30 root      0.0 [writeback]
     87 root      0.0 [watchdogd]
    101 root      0.0 [vfio-irqfd-clea]
     82 root      0.0 [tpm_dev_wq]
     11 root      0.0 [rcu_tasks_trace]
     10 root      0.0 [rcu_tasks_rude_]
     13 root      0.0 [rcu_sched]
      4 root      0.0 [rcu_par_gp]
      3 root      0.0 [rcu_gp]
     29 root      0.0 [oom_reaper]
     97 root      0.0 [nvme-wq]
     98 root      0.0 [nvme-reset-wq]
     99 root      0.0 [nvme-delete-wq]
      5 root      0.0 [netns]
      9 root      0.0 [mm_percpu_wq]
    103 root      0.0 [mld]
     20 root      0.0 [migration/1]
     14 root      0.0 [migration/0]
     84 root      0.0 [md]
    117 root      0.0 [kworker/u5:0]
   1880 root      0.0 [kworker/u4:2+loop1]
   1876 root      0.0 [kworker/u4:1-events_unbound]
   1926 root      0.0 [kworker/u4:0-events_power_efficient]
    693 root      0.0 [kworker/1:4-events]
    100 root      0.0 [kworker/1:1H-events_highpri]
     23 root      0.0 [kworker/1:0H-events_highpri]
   1885 root      0.0 [kworker/1:0-events]
     89 root      0.0 [kworker/0:1H-kblockd]
   1896 root      0.0 [kworker/0:1-events]
      7 root      0.0 [kworker/0:0H-events_highpri]
   1872 root      0.0 [kworker/0:0-events]
     95 root      0.0 [kthrotld]
      2 root      0.0 [kthreadd]
     92 root      0.0 [kswapd0]
    113 root      0.0 [kstrp]
     21 root      0.0 [ksoftirqd/1]
     12 root      0.0 [ksoftirqd/0]
     32 root      0.0 [ksmd]
    328 root      0.0 [kmpathd]
    327 root      0.0 [kmpath_rdacd]
    329 root      0.0 [kmpath_handlerd]
     79 root      0.0 [kintegrityd]
     28 root      0.0 [khungtaskd]
     33 root      0.0 [khugepaged]
     24 root      0.0 [kdevtmpfs]
     31 root      0.0 [kcompactd0]
     80 root      0.0 [kblockd]
     26 root      0.0 [kauditd]
    326 root      0.0 [kaluad]
    123 root      0.0 [jbd2/nvme0n1p1-]
    104 root      0.0 [ipv6_addrconf]
     25 root      0.0 [inet_frag_wq]
     19 root      0.0 [idle_inject/1]
     15 root      0.0 [idle_inject/0]
    124 root      0.0 [ext4-rsv-conver]
    214 root      0.0 [ena]
     85 root      0.0 [edac-poller]
     93 root      0.0 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
     86 root      0.0 [devfreq_wq]
    283 root      0.0 [cryptd]
     18 root      0.0 [cpuhp/1]
     17 root      0.0 [cpuhp/0]
    122 root      0.0 [charger_manager]
     81 root      0.0 [blkcg_punt_bio]
     83 root      0.0 [ata_sff]
     96 root      0.0 [acpi_thermal_pm]
    492 root      0.0 /usr/sbin/acpid
   1778 root      0.0 /bin/sh /etc/cron.daily/netbox-housekeeping
   1724 root      0.0 /bin/sh -c test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
    PID USER     %MEM COMMAND
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~# [41594.823220] sysrq: Show backtrace of all active CPUs

root@ip-172-31-45-233:~# # ps -ef | egrep -v "STIME|$LOGNAME" | sort +3 -r | head -n 15
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~# # ps -ef | egrep -v "STIME|$LOGNAME" | sort +3 -r | head -n 15

root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~# ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
    816 ttyS0    00:00:00 login
   1006 ttyS0    00:00:01 bash
   1934 ttyS0    00:00:00 ps

root@ip-172-31-45-233:~#

troot@ip-172-31-45-233:~#
root@ip-172-31-45-233:~# top
top - 12:07:47 up 11:38,  1 user,  load average: 20.88, 20.10, 19.60
Tasks: 117 total,   1 running, 116 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.1 us,  4.5 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id, 91.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  3.8 st
MiB Mem :    749.2 total,     40.5 free,    667.7 used,     41.0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.      8.5 avail Mem


    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
     92 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  11.6   0.0  65:08.23 kswapd0
    865 root      20   0 1314548   7468      0 S   1.4   1.0  84:33.11 ssm-age+
    611 root      20   0 1305364   5360      0 S   1.1   0.7  79:24.68 amazon-+
    639 root      20   0  874880  16000      0 S   0.5   2.1  29:55.16 snapd
   1935 root      20   0   11000   3384   2724 R   0.3   0.4   0:00.26 top
      1 root      20   0  168656   6452   3056 D   0.2   0.8   1:05.95 systemd
    165 root      19  -1   43964   4580   3140 D   0.2   0.6   0:07.11 systemd+
    491 root      20   0  241060   1084      8 S   0.2   0.1   0:27.40 account+
    737 redis     20   0   51708   2180    612 D   0.2   0.3   1:41.60 redis-s+
    862 netbox    20   0  126588  83756   1992 D   0.2  10.9   0:24.72 gunicorn
   1335 netbox    20   0  126588  82736    956 D   0.2  10.8   0:16.25 gunicorn
   1336 netbox    20   0  126596  82988   1200 D   0.2  10.8   0:16.89 gunicorn
   1779 root      20   0  131980  83100    808 D   0.2  10.8   0:28.10 python
   1876 root      20   0       0      0      0 D   0.2   0.0   0:01.27 kworker+
   1913 root      20   0  245280  25216   2412 D   0.2   3.3   0:03.28 unatten+
   1922 netbox    20   0   63296  23324   2168 D   0.2   3.0   0:02.65 python3
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.06 kthreadd
```

Comment: Please note that AWS t3.micro is 1 GB and not 2 GB memory. And, please monitor CPU usage also, because after a period of high CPU usage you may run out of AWS CPU credits.

Comment: @FedKad you are my best friend this week. Thanks.